# Fixing layout for this ListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, responsive-design

I understand there are lots of settings for setting layouts. Here is a `ListCtrl` of fixed dimensions inside a horizontal sizer.

[image]

This absolute size either displays leftover space or is too small depending on number of columns.

What are the layout commands to draw a `ListCtrl`?

How do I make the `ListCtrl` more responsive, so that it:

- shows data from many columns at a glance without needing a resize
- doesnt become bad on different GUIs and resizes

---

Code listing for the panel that hosts the list:

```
class CalcPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.lc = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, size=(200,200), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.lc.InsertColumn(0, 'State')
        self.lc.InsertColumn(1, 'Capital')
        #self.lc.SetColumnWidth(0, 140)
        #self.lc.SetColumnWidth(1, 153)
    #self.list_ctrl.Show()

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Add Line")

        self.sizer.Add(btn)
        self.sizer.Add(self.lc, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def InitUI(self):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [`wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin-class.html)?

if you inherit from `wx.lib.mixins.listctrl.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin` as well as `wx.ListCtrl`, and call the classes `__init__` in your `__init__` method the last column will auto resize with resize events

You can also change which column auto resizes with `setResizeColumn`

Comment: This pretty much blows my answer out of the water. I do find it weird that you need to use multiple inheritance, but I've foud a few code samples that do this so...

Comment: It is a bit weird, especially if you come from other languages. There's other mixins for list controls as well http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.mixins.listctrl-module.html

Comment: I meant more that other library classes like `wx.lib.scrolledpanel` don't require that kind of double inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an answer that was COMPLETELY wrong because I did not read the question anywhere near well enough. To make up for this mistake, I did some research and I think I have an answer that works.

Checking the `wx.ListCtrl` [API](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html), I've found a method `SetColumnWidth(self, col, width)` which I think does exactly what you want.

You said that your `wx.ListCtrl` is a fixed width? In that case...

```
lcWidth = 200
lcHeight = 200

self.lc = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, size=(lcWidth,lcHeight), style=wx.LC_REPORT)
self.lc.InsertColumn(0, 'State')
self.lc.InsertColumn(1, 'Capital')

stateWidth = self.lc.GetColumnWidth(0)
self.lc.SetColumnWidth(1, (lcWidth - stateWdith))
```

Incidently, if you wish your `wx.ListCtrl` to remain a fixed size, you should remove the `wx.GROW` flag from your `self.sizer.Add()` call. `wx.GROW` will resize the item so that it fills all the available space, not what you want.

```
self.sizer.Add(self.lc, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP)
```

If your `wx.ListCtrl` is NOT a fixed width, you could declare a custom `wx.ListCtrl` that handles this resizes accordingly

```
class ResizingColListCtrl (wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.sizeColumns()

        self.Bind(EVT_SIZE, self.sizeColumns)

    def sizeColumns(event=None)
        width = self.GetSize()[0]
        numCols = self.GetColumnCount()

        for i in range(numCols):
             self.SetColumnWidth(i, width/numCols) #set your column width to whatever proportions you want

        if event:
            event.Skip() #since this is a wx.EVT_SIZE, this line is important
```

So far as I can tell, wxPython does not have this functionality natively.